# GAE/J: how do I get a User object from the user-id? Alt: how come I can't set the nickname on a User object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Suppose in Java Google App Engine (GAE/J) I use the com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService to get the User object for the current user.

I want to send the information about this user to the client; however since I'm using Google Web Toolkit (GWT), I need an object that I can serialize and User is not one of those because it belongs to a server package.

Therefore I make a new class in my GWT shared directory called, say, UserStuff and I copy the fields of User into an instance of a UserStuff and send it to the client.

Later the client sends the UserStuff object back to me and I want to attach the user as a property of an Entity.  The only way to make a User object that I can find is to call the constructor for User myself; that is, nothing in the UserService API will get a fully-formed User object for me from just, say, a user-id (gotten from User.getUserId()) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService

So I make a User object using the constructor for User.  None of these constructors allow me to set the nickname field on the User, nor is there a method to do so! https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User

Now, I can instead have the client send a token back saying "get the current user and use that", but that is clunky.  Further, it is even more problematic if I have entities that have multiple users attached to them and I want to send them to the client and have the client send me back more objects to put into the datastore which should have other users attached to the entity.

One way to do it is to just make a UserStuff entity for each user and when I get the User as the current user, file the User as a field on that user's UserStuff object along with the user's !user-id.  Then when I want the User object for a user-id, I can get the UserStuff object for that user-id and then get the user's User object as a property on the UserStuff object.  Or I could just put the nickname on the UserStuff object.  However this is a lot of extra datastore traffic just because I can't set the nickname on a User object.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to get a user object given the ID unless you stored the original user object in the datastore. Likewise, there's no way to change the nickname on a user.

The User object is only designed to encapsulate basic information about the logged in user; if you want extra information or behaviour (such as a user-set nickname), you should create your own UserInfo model, and use that instead. You can set its key name to the user ID of the user object, so you can find the UserInfo for a logged in user with a simple get operation.